# What does it mean that deviance(model) = NA?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I am trying to run a GLM model using the `lme4` package. My variable is

[image: discrete]

so I used a Poisson distribution, However, I'm encountering an issue with a significantly high unconditional absolute 'deviance.' However, I'm encountering an issue with a notoriously high unconditional absolute 'deviance.' Additionally, when testing for conditional relative deviance, the output returns as 'NA.' Any insights or suggestions on addressing this issue would be greatly appreciated!. Here is the model summary:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [
glmerMod]
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: il.1b ~ stage + (1 | jaula)
   Data: data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 23266.7  23276.4 -11630.3  23260.7      184 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-19.4624  -8.1219  -0.2759   6.8769  27.0264 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 jaula  (Intercept) 0.2139   0.4625  
Number of obs: 187, groups:  jaula, 48

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  5.856860   0.066995   87.42   <2e-16 ***
stageb      -0.001126   0.007529   -0.15    0.881    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
       (Intr)
stageb -0.057
> deviance(il.1b1)
[1] NA
```

I have also tested a negative binomial distribution with a similar output.

Comment: `deviance.merMod` just extracts the deviance residuals from the model object and calculates their sum of squares. Do you see `NA` values in `residuals(il.1b1)`? Can you try fitting the model with a higher `nAGQ` value, e.g., `nAGQ = 20`?